# Deleting files from gcp bucket and replacing them cause non-deterministic behavior

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket at `gs://my-bucket` and a two files in it:

- `gs://my-bucket/dir/index.html`
- `gs://my-bucket/dir/file1.js`

Locally, I have the following files in the `dir` directory:

- `index.html`
- `file2.js`

I then run the following command:

`gsutil rm -r gs://my-bucket/dir && gsutil cp -z js -r dir gs://my-bucket`

After this it run, I'm able to view both `file1.js` AND `file2.js` via direct url even though `file1.js` has been deleted:

- `https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/dir/file1.js // 200 OK`
- `https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/dir/file2.js // 200 OK`

Also, if I try to visit `https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/dir/index.html`, sometimes I get the old contents of that file, and sometimes the new contents. The behavior is seemingly non-deterministic.

What is going on? Is there some caching at the bucket level? Can I turn this behavior off?

Comment: how do you perform you test? With your browser? With curl command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a silly mistake where I was caching on my server that was actually serving up the files. To debug this, Guillarme's comment is apt -- start with a curl on the files directly from google and see where on your stack the caching is occuring.